# Get current datetime in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How in defaults get current datetime and current datetime + 1 hour?

For date I use below example:

```
defaults = {
                 'start': fields.Date.today(),
                 'finish': fields.Date.today(),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

defaults = {
    'start': datetime.now(),
    'finish': datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1),
}
```

And your field declaration will be *start,* *finish* as *datetime* data-type.

Answer (score 1):

And following a solution for the "new" API, which i recommend you to use, because you tagged Odoo-9:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from openerp import models, fields, api
# from odoo import models, fields, api  # for Odoo 10+


class MyClass(models.Model):
    _name = "my.class"

    start = fields.Date(string="Start", default="_default_start")
    finish = fields.Date(string="Finish", default="_default_finish")

    @api.model
    def _default_start(self):
        return fields.Date.context_today(self)

    @api.model
    def _default_finish(self):
        finish = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
        return fields.Date.context_today(self, timestamp=finish)
```

Answer (score 1):

for the new api in odoo there is a `default` option in the fields, and you can create a **function** to set the default option two

```
start = fields.Datetime('Date', default=fields.Datetime.now,)
finish = fields.Datetime('Date', default='_get_finish_date',)

from datetime import datetime , timedelta
@api.one
def _get_finish_date(self):
    return  datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: can you explain why this is a solution? Code only answers are rarely very helpful to providing any insight to solutions to issues

Comment: @Martin what do you want to know